# String List parsing

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

I have a string that is like this:

> Item1;Item2;Item3

but could also be

> Item1

Is there a slick .net method to get that into a List?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ has a way to bring the array to string, too:

```
var inputString = "item1;item2;item3";
var asList = inputString.Split( ';' ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

[`string.split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) is your friend...

Answer (score 5):

```
var yourString = "Item1;Item2;Item3";

var result = new List<string>(yourString.Split(';'));
```

Comment: I think `Split` method has an overload to pass a char instead of Array to be: `yourString.Split(';')`

Comment: It exists in the [first one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) check `params`

Comment: Microsoft does document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx says the signature is params char[]. params is the important part. See definition of params http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(VS.71).aspx. You can actually do yourString.Split(';', 'a', ',') if you want to split by multiple chars.

Comment: @Homam - Doh! Good call. Deleting my comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "Item1;Item2;Item3";
var list = input.Split(new[] {";"}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do that:

```
string[] arr = str.Split( new char[] { ';' } );
List<string> list = new List<string>( arr );
```